# Searching for a single in a SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am new to mySQL and PHP and I'm stuck into a performance problem.
I have a database with different unique ids and I want to extract several rows by id (from an array) out of over 5000. The best solution I came up so far is to use:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id IN ($idArray);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? The 'id' in 'table' is a unique string.

Comment: why is the ids strings?

Comment: If the ids *are* unique - as in they have unique indexes (`PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE`) in the database then, on a mere 5000 records, that should be quick as s--- off a shovel!

Comment: This is about as efficient as it's going to get, just make sure you have an index on the `id` field.

Comment: passing variables to your query like that can make you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: The ids are Facebook User Ids, which are numeric strings of ~15 characters, give or take. I'm using the database as a Leaderboard, and to be more concrete, I want to extract the scores (~4 colomns per user) of all the user's friends (with their ids). At this point I've only tested ~10 people from 5000 total users, self-generated, but in reality it could be several hundreds out of more than 50k total users. Is this still efficient? If I'm not already heading towards off-topic, do you think there's a better way for doing what I intend to? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen 70,000 numbers in an `IN` list be "sluggish".

Part of the issue is indexing.  Your `table` needs `INDEX(id)` (or, better yet, `PRIMARY KEY(id)`).

Part of the issue is caching.  If `table` is small enough to fit in the buffer_pool, and that cache is warm, then it is more like warm and wet stuff falling off a shovel.

But... If your "array" is *already* in a table, then simply `JOIN` to that table.  That will probably be faster.  OTOH, building a table just for this purpose will probably be slower.